# Problema para validar existencia de un Email C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

Estoy intentando correr una app para validar la existencia de un correo electrónico, la comunicación se hace a través de sockets pero me genera un error cuando verifica el servidor smtp

> Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte
> conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien
> se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host
> conectado no ha podido responder 104.47.66.33:465

ya intente cambiarle el puerto a 2525,587,25,465 pero no funciona se queda hasta la linea IPEndPoint y genera el error mencionado.

```html
public bool VerifySmtpResponse(string strSmtpServerURL, string strEmailAddress)
        {
            IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strSmtpServerURL);
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0],465);

            using (Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                tcpSocket.Connect(endPoint);

                if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 220))
                {
                    tcpSocket.Close();
                    return false;
                }

                //HELO server
                SendData(tcpSocket, string.Format("HELO {0}\r\n", Dns.GetHostName()));
                if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 250))
                {
                    tcpSocket.Close();
                    return false;
                }

                //Identify yourself
                //Servers may resolve your domain and check whether 
                //you are listed in BlackLists etc.
                SendData(tcpSocket, string.Format("MAIL From: {0}\r\n", MailFrom));
                if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 220))
                {
                    tcpSocket.Close();
                    return false;
                }

                //Attempt Delivery (I can use VRFY, but most 
                //SMTP servers only disable it for security reasons)
                SendData(tcpSocket, strEmailAddress);
                if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 220))
                {
                    tcpSocket.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return (true);
        }
```

Comment: Haz verificado la conectividad de forma externa al programa, como una prueba de red desde un cliente mail que se conecte al host en el puerto especificado? Para ver si el problema es del código o de algo en la infraestructura, como routing o reglas de firewall?

Comment: Podria ser que el servidor al cual pertenece el mail a verificar tenga aplicado un timeout para evitar spam (así lo hago yo en el mio con un timeout de 10 segundos antes de permitir nuevas instrucciones por smtp... no sabes la de spam que te libras, je), y entonces tu código, que no espera, no funcione por ello. Prueba con otros emails/dominios/servidores a ver si tambien te pasa.